# Accessing new row added to a table - Error object doesn't support property

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching for a while to understand what's wrong. Sometimes it seems to work and other time nothing. I don't know why and what I am doing wrong.

This is the code

```
Private Sub AddToTable(table_name As String, myarray() As String)
    'Dim newrow As ListRow
  
    For i = LBound(myarray) To UBound(myarray)
    
        Set newrow = Sheet_Parametre.ListObjects(table_name).ListRows.Add
        newrow.Cells(1) = myarray(i)
    
    Next i

End Sub
```

I don't know why the new row is accessible and sometimes not.
Sometimes it will run for the first item I add but not the second. Now it's not even working at all.

I tried different way with no more success

```
Sheet_Parametre.ListObjects(table_name).ListRows.Add
Sheet_Parametre.ListObjects(table_name).ListRows(Sheet_Parametre.ListObjects(table_name).ListRows.Count).Range(1) = myarray(i)
```

```
        With Sheet_Parametre.ListObjects(table_name).ListRows
            .Add AlwaysInsert:=True
        End With
        With Sheet_Parametre.ListObjects(table_name).ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
            .Range(1) = myarray(i)
        End With
```

Comment: `Sheet_Parametre.ListObjects(table_name).listrows.add.range.cells(1)` will be the first cell in the new row

Comment: I made an error, my code is With Sheet_Parametre.ListObjects(table_name).ListRows.Add 
            .Range(1) = myarray(i)
        End With

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```vb
Private Sub AddToTable(table_name As String, myarray() As String)
    With Sheet_Parametre.ListObjects(table_name).ListRows.Add.Range
        'assuming my array is a 1D zero-based array...
        '   and the values fit on the new row
        .Cells(1).Resize(1, UBound(myarray) + 1).Value = myarray
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

My code is correct, the issue is with the data that is getting added to the table was starting with =.
So that's not possible. I modified it to add a '= if it start with a =.
I also try to prevent anyone adding that symbol at beginning.